# How is $0^x$ defined (seriously)?

Tags: exponentiation

Normally, $a^b$ is defined as $e^{b \ln(a)}$ and $e^x$ is defined by its Maclaurin Series, and $\ln(x)$ is defined as the real inverse of $e^x$. If we try this with $0^x$, we get $e^{x \ln(0)}$, which is obviously incorrect. Of course we can just define it separately, and say $0^x = 0$ for $x \gt 0$ (or $\geq$ 0 if you're feeling spicy), but this feels inelegant.

Comment: All mathematicians agree in $0^x=0$ for positive $x$.  A lot mathematicians have very good reasons (the binomial theorem, Taylor expansion are only two of them) to define $0^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Maclurin series you mentioned to find that
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\delta^x=0$$
and hence $0^x=0$ (of course for positive $x$ only).

Does that help?

Comment: For positive $x$ ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Ah yes! For negative $x$, it's not defined.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe okay now?

Comment: Yes, but you're telling nothing new: we all agree in $0^x=0$ for positive $x$ ...

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Yes, that was what the question asked, I guess. It asked why do we agree on that. And, I gave a reason to do so.